# Extracting URLs from a text file

Tags: python, regex, url, beautifulsoup, extract

How do I extract links which I have saved in a text file one by one to use it in my other code:-

Example of a link in a text file is:-

```
http://www.barneys.com/givenchy-poplin-field-shirt-504068255.html
```

I have got only URLs in my text file and no multiple URLs in a single line.

And my other code in which I have to use the link(s) is:-

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url=" " #here I have to use the links one by one
r=requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Do you know how to open and read a file? The fact that you're getting URLs from it is **completely irrelevant**.

Comment: What is in your text file ?  Are there only URLs, or other text too?  Could there be multiple URLs on any given line?

Comment: I didn't follow you. What I have to do is, save the links in a text file and then use them in my other code to get the relevant details from that link one by one.

Comment: No, only URLs I have, there are no multiple URLs in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    urls = f.readlines()

urls = ([s.strip('\n') for s in urls ])


for url in urls:
    # insert code here to do whatever you want with one url
```

Is this all you want? This will read each line in and store it to this list.

edited to strip '\n' character in list elements

Comment: well you have a list of the urls now, so enumerate over them

Comment: you need `.strip()` to escape '\n'

Comment: I didn't follow you @Dportology. I am new to python, please help me with the code..thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use this code, and replace "file_name" with the path to your text file containing the urls. These urls will then be stored in the urls list, and you can use them however you want. I don't know what you want to do with them but your options are open I guess!

Comment: This is my code:- http://pastebin.com/SnrTXAZB I want to use each url one by one. Please see my code and suggest me something...Thanks. @Dportology

Comment: see edits for how to use each url one by one. good luck Vaibhav.